# Same scale for all the axes in Plot3D

Tags: plotting

I can't find this in the documentation. How do you force the same scale for all the axes when making a 3D plot? There is the `BoxRatios` option, but this only changes the dimensions of the visible box with no regard to the actual scales of the axis.

Comment: Set that option you just found to `Automatic` and report back.

Comment: Shouldn't it be BoxRatios -> 1
?

Comment: @Feyre, you can answer your own question by trying to plot a function like $x^2+y^2$. Note the shape of the box, and then note the numbers on the ticks.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. yes that worked, thank you.

Comment: Then, please answer your own question. :)

Answer (score 3):

Only `BoxRatios` will not solve your problem. You have to fix the `PlotRange` also. For example take `2(x^2+y^2)`

```
Plot3D[2 (x^2 + y^2), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, BoxRatios -> 1, FaceGrids -> All]
```

[image]

As you can see the unit along `z` direction is twice compared to `x` and `y` (that's why I choose `2 (x^2 + y^2)`, to make this point)

Now you fix the `PlotRange`

```
plrange = {-1, 1};
Plot3D[2 (x^2 + y^2), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
 FaceGrids -> All, PlotRange -> {plrange, plrange, plrange + 1}]
```

[image]

And your units are same in all directions.

Comment: Certainly, an inappropriate setting of `BoxRatios` will not fix OP's problem. Set properly, one will not have to fiddle with `PlotRange` unless desired.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning explicitly that if you do not want to display a cubic domain, then you can do some math between BoxRatios and PlotRange. Example if you want PlotRange->{ {-a,b},{-c,d},{-h,j} }, then you need BoxRatios->{ a+b, c+d, h+j }. It may also be worth noting that this may be inexact. I can see on my plot that some of the axes are slightly larger than the domain specified by PlotRange. However, it seems to make a nearly unnoticeable visual difference.